# Making my query more secure with (prepared statement)

Tags: php, mysql, security, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am figuring out how I could make the following query more secure:
I have already used `mysqli_real_escape_string` but i doubt that adds much to security.

I have looked into the following:
http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

but I also have to take into account the following line:

```
    $check_customer = mysqli_num_rows($run_c);
```

Below are the codes

```
   $c_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
        $c_pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);
        $couponCodeLogin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['couponCodeLogin']);
$couponCodeLoginAmount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['couponCodeLoginAmount']);

        $sel_c = "select * from customers where customer_pass='$c_pass' AND customer_email='$c_email'";

        $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $sel_c);
        $check_customer = mysqli_num_rows($run_c); 
        if($check_customer==0){

        echo "<script>
        document.getElementById('loginError').innerHTML = 'Password or email is incorrect, please try again.'
        </script>";
        exit();
        }


        if($check_customer>0){
                    $crs_id = $_GET['crs_id'];

     $insert_c = "insert into customers (customer_email,coupon_code_login,coupon_code_login_amount) values ('$c_email','$couponCodeLogin','$couponCodeLoginAmount')";
                $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c); 


                $_SESSION['userCoupon'] = $_POST['couponCodeLoginAmount'];

        $_SESSION['customer_email']=$c_email; 
                        $_SESSION['userCouponName'] = $_POST['couponCodeLogin'];


        echo "<script>window.open('coursePayment.php?crs_id=$crs_id','_self')</script>";

        }
        else {
        $_SESSION['customer_email']=$c_email; 


        echo "<script>window.open('coursePayment.php?crs_id=$crs_id','_self')</script>";

        $_SESSION['userCoupon'] = $_POST['couponCodeLoginAmount'];
                $_SESSION['userCouponName'] = $_POST['couponCodeLogin'];

        }
    }
```

and

```
        $fname= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['fname']);
        $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['lname']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
        $pnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pnumber']);       
 $couponCodeRegister=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['couponCodeRegister']);
$couponCodeRegisterAmount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['couponCodeRegisterAmount']);

        $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);
        $cname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['cname']);
        $cposition = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['cposition']);


         $insert_c = "insert into customers (customer_fname,customer_lname,customer_email,customer_number,customer_pass,customer_cname,customer_cposition,coupon_code_register,coupon_code_register_amount) values ('$fname','$lname','$email','$pnumber','$pass','$cname','$cposition','$couponCodeRegister','$couponCodeRegisterAmount')";

        $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $insert_c); 


        $insert_email = "select * from customers";
        $run_email = mysqli_query($con, $insert_email);

        $find_email = mysqli_fetch_array($run_email);
        $demail = $find_email['customer_email'];     

        if($email!= $demail)
       {
         $crs_id = $_GET['crs_id'];

         $_SESSION['userCoupon'] = $_POST['couponCodeRegisterAmount'];
         $_SESSION['userCouponName'] = $_POST['couponCodeRegister'];
         $_SESSION['customer_email']=$email; 

         echo "<script>
         document.getElementById('registerError').innerHTML = 'Account has been created successfully, Thanks!'
         </script>";
         echo "<script>window.open('coursePayment.php?crs_id=$crs_id','_self')</script>";

       }
```

Comment: This likely belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If the code works as expected and you are looking for improvements, you are welcome to delete your question here and post it to the Code Review site if you want. You might want to add a bit more context and write a title that says what the code does, rather than what you would like reviewed about it.